# Does Mia Khalifa speak English with an accent?

Tags: dialects, speech, non-native-english

She immigrated to America at age 7 (other sources say ten) she seems quite fluent to me.

From Wikipedia

> Khalifa attended a French-language private school in Beirut, where she also learned to speak English.[3] She moved with her family to the United States in 2001,[4] leaving their home in the wake of the South Lebanon conflict

Sample from [Youtube: BBC HARDtalk interview.](https://yewtu.be/watch?v=i2qplvJ6SLs&t=100s)

Comment: Everyone speaks English with some form of accent.

Comment: I believe the OP meant _foreign (non-native) accent_ that is influenced from a first language, and there is the "non-native-english" tag as well; although the OP could clarify with additional wording.

Comment: @ermanen Well, American is a foreign accent! But yes, I can't discern a French or Arabic twang to the American.

Comment: 7-10 is still early enough to have a native accent, in general.

Comment: I can hear no trace of a non-English accent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. She speaks English with an American accent. Others may be able to be more specific about *which* American accent.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a Minnesota accent.

Comment: Didn't listen to the whole thing (just her first response) and there really isn't anything in her speech to suggest she isn't American-born.

Comment: She has a flat midwestern accent, which news readers use, and could be described as neutral. I would think it is the American counterpart to British RP.